# Reducing to 1 in fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, education

I asked this question on another page but haven’t received a response as it’s not as active.

Last night I was fiddling with some equations and admittedly, I made a careless mistake because I was exhausted. However, in doing so, I began to question the process of what I used to understand as "cancelling" in fractions. The equation was:

(6 ÷ 2)/2

I cancelled the divison by 2 with the 2 in the denominator.

After some research, I came to realise that a better term is reduction to 1 as it is a better indication of what we are actually doing when simplifying fractions.

However, I would like to know the reason why we can't do what I did because if a student asks, I would like to see if there is an explanation beyond BODMAS.

Also, I do believe that we can only cancel factors but if a student were to say ((6 ÷ (2)(1))/2, we now have factors that we seem to be able to cancel, but because of the division in the numerator, we cannot. Is there a more articulate and mathematically correct way of putting this?

Looking forward to this discussion!

EDIT: Please explain why this has been downvoted. If there is an issue with the question, please provide some constructive criticism.

Comment: Since $6/2=3$, we have $((6/2)/2)=3/2$, so we cannot cancel. This is all.

Comment: I suppose a good practice for cancelling factors in nested divisions is to first bring the term down to a single fraction and then do standard factor cancelling.

Comment: @AndreasLenz that’s fair enough. Thank you for your reply. Perhaps K am trying to read too much into something that doesn’t need it. I will leave the question in case someone comes up with something creative :) thank you again

Comment: It's a question about rules. It's not in the rules for fractions to do cancellations as you suggest. It's like with any rule based game, say chess for concreteness. There is no rule for the knight to move diagonally. So a diagonal move of the knight is not valid in chess. Of course you can adjust the rules so that the knight may move diagonally, then you are not playing chess anymore but another game. You can change the rules of fraction cancellation. You are still doing math, not usual fraction math but a custom version. However such custom versions have not been too useful for most purposes.

Comment: The calcellation laws are $(a\times b)\div (c\times b)=a\div c$ and $(a\div b)\div(c\div b)=a\div c$ (provided all the relevant things aren't $0$). Neither of these applies to your case.

Comment: In $6\div2$, $2$ isn't a factor, so "cancelling factors" doesn't apply.

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}/c=\frac{a}{bc}$, that's why one can do this. Example $(12\div 7)\div 9=(4\div 7)\div 3$.

Comment: Parentheses are your friends.  They dictate the order of operations.  Omitting them can cause ambiguity.  That's about all that can be added to the "discussion", and I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression of the form $\Large{\frac{a\cdot x}{b\cdot x}}$ can be simplified to $\Large{\frac{a}{b}}$ assuming $x\ne 0$.

@AndreasLenz’s suggestion to simplify nested divisions is a good one.

Often I found it useful to rewrite $\LARGE{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}}$ as $\Large{\frac{a\cdot d}{b\cdot c}}$.

I remember this rule as: Dividing by a fraction is the same as multiplying by its reciprocal.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ahaaa yes. Thank you for your input. That helps :)